# Google Mobile Payments Library - does it exist?

Tags: android, mobile, payment

I've finished implementing the PayPal Express Checkout Library (MECL) into my Android App - eventhough it is AWESOME, I would like to give my customers more choice.

So I thought I'd search for "Google Mobile Payments Library" but only the PayPal library is returned in search results.

Does Google have a mobile payments library to implement in my App ?

Comment: embed or integrate maybe? Implement is do it by yourself from scratch.

Comment: @someone Somewhere  i having problem in integrating MECL with my application... the problem is i am not able to set the amount..

Comment: Hello, Can i get some code for Mobile Express Checkout library. I've been stuck this payment method for 10 days. Please see this question on [StackoverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499836/android-how-do-i-pass-the-payment-details)

Comment: SpK, in the end I did not use the MECL because I ran into painful problems! Instead, I simply used the MPL and called it a day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out Google's In-App Billing platform yet?  It's relatively new, beginning of Feb.  If you haven't already, check it out.

http://d.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: this is pretty much your only option, Google has started removing apps from the market that do in-app payments by other means.

Comment: good find! it gives sample code; not a drop-n-go solution like PayPal, but still does the job.

Comment: schwiz, do you have a link that gives more info ? Google removing apps from the Market that use PayPal would seem like an anti-competitive practice.