# Using JodaTime in project for Australia

Tags: android, timezone, jodatime

I am somewhat new to Android but have heeded the advice by many programmers to use JodaTime for all the time calculations in my project. However I can't seem to use JodaTime to convert UTC time to Australian Timezones. Am I supposed to recompile JodaTime for Australia? If so, how?
I tried using the DateTimeZone.getAvailableIds() function but the returned array doesn't list any Australian timezones.

Can someone please explain what I need to do it would be very much appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Joda Time have you got - is it a specifically "cut down" version for Android? There should be several, such as "Australia/Melbourne" and "Australia/Sydney".

Comment: It is version 2.0. It was downloaded directly from the SourgeForge website. It was just the "standard" distribution ZIP file listed there. I see there is now version 2.1. I will download it and see if there is any difference.

Comment: That really shouldn't be the problem. How big was the set returned by getAvailableIds?

Comment: Just tried version 2.1. Gives a different set of AvailableIds. In each case it seems to be returning 64 items.

Comment: Sorry. Previous comment is incorrect. It was returning all the TimeZones (100s of them). I have not come across a Set before and was handling it incorrectly. I have things working now apart from the creation of a DateTime object taking so long. All I need to do now is figure out how to modify the provider to handle only Australian and UTC timezones and everything will be fine.

Comment: Jon I noticed in another post you talked about building JodaTime using "with a very much reduced time zone database". Can you please tell me how to do this? Do I remove files from the main\java\org\joda\time\tz\src folder leaving just the australasia file and editing the etc file down to just UTC records or something? Is there any trick to compiling JodaTime? Remember I'm and Android infant..:) Thanks

Comment: I think you'd need to run the ZoneInfoCompiler after removing the relevant time zones (and then rebuild the jar file, of course). I can't remember the details of how Joda Time "discovers" time zones, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your final comment, if you just want to filter the time zones to those starting with Australia (or UTC), you could use:

```
// Easier with Guava, but you might not want another dependency
List<DateTimeZone> zones = new ArrayList<DateTimeZone>();
for (String id : DateTimeZone.getAvailableIds()) {
    if (id.startsWith("Australia/")) {
        zones.add(DateTimeZone.forID(id));
    }
}
zones.add(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

(Obviously if you just want the IDs, you need to make it a `List<String>` and use `zones.add(id)`.)

Comment: Do you work with `Mobile Express Checkout Library` on android? If yes means, please help me on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499836/android-how-do-i-pass-the-payment-details)

Comment: Okay sir. But, very very thanks for your response through comment.

Comment: Ok. That looks like what I want to do. But exactly where is that code to go. Is it code that needs to go into a JodaTime library or my app? If in the app, where in relation to the creation of a DateTime object?

Comment: @user91705: In your app - but I've no idea where it would go, I'm afraid, without knowing anything about your application.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Jon. Where did you get that bit of code from? Would that give me some idea where to put it?

Comment: @user917051: I didn't get it from anywhere. I understood that you wanted to filter the set of time zone IDs by ones which started with "Australia/" - that's all.

Comment: Well yeah I do (I think). If the DateTime objects are taking a long time to create because of a large timezone database sitting behind them, surely the fix is to somehow reduce that database down to only the timezones I want to deal with. I can't figure out if I need to "filter" out the non-required timezones inside the JodaTime library or in the application itself. It seems the Eclipse/Android environment is way more difficult to deal with then the .NET one and documentation seems way too sparse. I would be totally lost if it wasn't for the assistance from guys like yourself. Thanks so much.

Comment: @user917051: It depends where the time's actually being spent. If you only need a certain set of time zones though, it would make a lot of sense to include a customized jar file - aside from anything else, you won't be wasting *space* with all those time zones you don't need.